# Browse a string matrix and store it in a vector of vector

Tags: c++, string, parsing, matrix, vector

I have this matrix in a string :

```
-78.45 5120 45.369 7.456
-0.140 1.012 1.161 7.456
-4.4287 8.963 1.121 7898
-8.753 8.159 3.852 2.415
0.000 2.456 4.655 6.041
0.000 3.132 8.275 1.788
7.489 8.056 7.288 5.698
4.050 7.456 7.340 2.025
0.090 9.478 9.395 6.416
1.132 6.866 8.450 2.126
6.222 5.142 7.596 0.56
9.121 2.256 5.641 3.741
8.896 1.488 2.858 2.456
```

I would like to browse it and store it in a matrix vector or a matrix of float.
I can actually store it in a single vector, this is the functional code :

```
int main()
{
    std::istringstream str(
        "-78.45 5120 45.369 7.456\n"
        "-0.140 1.012 1.161 7.456\n"
        "-4.4287 8.963 1.121 7898\n"
        "-8.753 8.159 3.852 2.415\n"
        "0.000 2.456 4.655 6.041\n"
        "0.000 3.132 8.275 1.788\n"
        "7.489 8.056 7.288 5.698\n"
        "4.050 7.456 7.340 2.025\n"
        "0.090 9.478 9.395 6.416\n"
        "1.132 6.866 8.450 2.126\n"
        "6.222 5.142 7.596 0.56\n"
        "9.121 2.256 5.641 3.741\n"
        "8.896 1.488 2.858 2.456\n");

    std::string space = " ";
    std::string line;
    size_t l_position = 0;
    std::vector<float> vectorNumber;
    while (std::getline(str, line)) {
        while ((l_position = line.find(space)) != std::string::npos)
        {
            float nombre = std::stof(line.substr(0, l_position));
            vectorNumber.push_back(nombre);
            line.erase(0, l_position + space.length());
        }
        vectorNumber.push_back(std::stof(line));
    }

    int w = 0;
    for(vector<float>::iterator it=vectorNumber.begin(); it!=vectorNumber.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
        w++;
        if (w==4){
            cout << endl;
            w = 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to store it in a vector of vector, the last block of numbers of each line is deleted and I don't know why. I am going crazy, can you help me ?

This is my code :

```
int main()
{
    std::istringstream str(
        "-78.45 5120 45.369 7.456\n"
        "-0.140 1.012 1.161 7.456\n"
        "-4.4287 8.963 1.121 7898\n"
        "-8.753 8.159 3.852 2.415\n"
        "0.000 2.456 4.655 6.041\n"
        "0.000 3.132 8.275 1.788\n"
        "7.489 8.056 7.288 5.698\n"
        "4.050 7.456 7.340 2.025\n"
        "0.090 9.478 9.395 6.416\n"
        "1.132 6.866 8.450 2.126\n"
        "6.222 5.142 7.596 0.56\n"
        "9.121 2.256 5.641 3.741\n"
        "8.896 1.488 2.858 2.456\n");

    std::string space = " ";
    std::string line;
    size_t l_position = 0;
    std::vector<float> vectorNumber;
    std::vector<vector<float>> vectorOfVectorNumber;
    while (std::getline(str, line)) {
        while ((l_position = line.find(space)) != std::string::npos)
        {
            float nombre = std::stof(line.substr(0, l_position));
            vectorNumber.push_back(nombre);
            line.erase(0, l_position + space.length());
        }
        vectorOfVectorNumber.push_back(vectorNumber);
    }
    int w = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorOfVectorNumber.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < vectorOfVectorNumber[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << vectorOfVectorNumber[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would like the simplest solution to store it, even if it's in a float tab of tab.

Comment: You miss the last one because you search for a space, but there's no space at the end of your lines, there is only `\n`. Instead of doing this by hand, I suggest you create a stringstream from your line string and just read numbers from that.

Comment: Note that not only is the flat vector easier to read into, it is actually the most efficient way to store a matrix anyway (so long as the matrix is dense. Other representations are better for spare matrices), so it might be worth considering to keep using the working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the code quite a lot (and fixing it at the same time) by using standard C++ operations and functions:

```
std::istringstream str(
"-78.45 5120 45.369 7.456\n"
"-0.140 1.012 1.161 7.456\n"
"-4.4287 8.963 1.121 7898\n"
"-8.753 8.159 3.852 2.415\n"
"0.000 2.456 4.655 6.041\n"
"0.000 3.132 8.275 1.788\n"
"7.489 8.056 7.288 5.698\n"
"4.050 7.456 7.340 2.025\n"
"0.090 9.478 9.395 6.416\n"
"1.132 6.866 8.450 2.126\n"
"6.222 5.142 7.596 0.56\n"
"9.121 2.256 5.641 3.741\n"
"8.896 1.488 2.858 2.456\n");

std::vector<std::vector<float>> matrix;

std::string line;
while (std::getline(str, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    matrix.emplace_back(std::istream_iterator<float>(iss), std::istream_iterator<float>());
}
```

See e.g. [here](https://ideone.com/SEkxct) for a working example and how to print each element

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your second loop `while ((l_position = line.find(space)) != std::string::npos)` this skips the last entry, since it doesn't find a space. To fix this you can use another stringstream. You also need to bring your `vector<float>` before the inner while loop, The entire thing looks like this:

```
while (std::getline(str, line)) {

    stringstream ss(line);
    string number = "";
    std::vector<float> vectorNumber;
    while (std::getline(ss,number,' '))
    {
        vectorNumber.push_back(stof(number));
    }
    vectorOfVectorNumber.push_back(vectorNumber);
}
```